# Map Json Property With Period To Class Property in Spring Controller

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I have a json object being sent to a controller that maps to a class model.  The json contains the property below

```
"Event.GradeBook.GradeEvent": {  }
```

How can I represent this in a class model where it will map correctly?

```
String Event_Gradebook_GradeEvent;
```

Comment: Sent how to your controller? As a `application/json` body? Let's see your handler method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Spring's default Jackson deserialization, all you need to do is annotate your field with `@JsonProperty`.

```
@JsonProperty(value = "Event.GradeBook.GradeEvent")
private String Event_Gradebook_GradeEvent;
```

But you should really follow Java's naming conventions.

Comment: That worked, yes my property name isnt like that but I wanted to give a visual on what I thought might be the correct answer.

Comment: Do you know how to do this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670456/map-post-parameter-to-model-in-spring-controller?